# When to use const with objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I recently read about ES6 `const` keyword and I can understand its importance when having something like this:

```
(function(){
    const PI = 3.14;
    PI = 3.15; //  Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable
})();
```

So, nobody can change my `PI` variable.

The misunderstanding I have is that I don't understand in which situation the use of `const` with objects can make sense (other than preventing people to do `myObj = newValue;`).

```
(function(){
    const obj = {a:1 ,b: 2, c:3};
    //obj = {x:7 , y:8, z: 9}
    //This is good
    //TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

    obj.a=7; obj.b=8 ; obj.c=9;
    console.log(obj); //outputs: {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}
})();
```

So when declaring an object: when should I say: Now I **must** declare my object with `const`?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

it is a common misconception around the web, `CONST` doesn't creates immutable variables instead it creates immutable binding.

eg.

```
 const temp1 = 1;
 temp1  = 2 //error thrown here.
```

But

```
 temp1.temp = 3 // no error here. Valid JS code as per ES6
```

so `const` creates a binding to that particular object. const assures that variable `temp1` won't have any other object's Binding.

Now coming to `Object`. we can get immutable feature with `Object` by using `Object.freeze`

```
const temp3 = Object.freeze( {a:3,b:4})
temp3.a = 2 // it wont update the value of a, it still have 3
temp3.c = 6 // still valid but wont change the object
```

Comment: thank you for the clear answer. Can you just please explain how "`const` assures that variable `temp1` won't have any other object's Binding."?

Comment: any reference stating that?

Comment: @TechTurtle , execute above example in your browser's console

Comment: @TechTurtle I'm a bit late for this, but just for the sake of completeness: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is the reference for `const` and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) is the reference for `Object.freeze()`.

Comment: not valid in strict mode though, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'temp' on number '1'`

Answer (score 24):

According to [ES6-Features.org](http://es6-features.org/#Constants), constants are used to make "variables which cannot be re-assigned new content".

The `const` keyword makes a variable itself immutable, not its assigned content. When the content is an object, this means the object itself can still be altered.

Therefore, it's possible to change the content of the object that is declared with `const` variable, but you cannot assign a new object to a `const` variable.

You are still allowed to add new attributes to your object.

```js
const myVar = "someValue";
const myObj = {"name": "nameValue", "age": 14}

console.log(myVar); //someValue
console.log(myObj.name); //nameValue

myObj.name = "newNameValue"; 
console.log(myObj.name); //newNameValue

myObj.someNewAttr = "newAttrValue";
console.log(myObj.someNewAttr); //newAttrValue

myObj = {"newNameAttr": "newNameValue"}; //Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
console.log(myObj.newNameAttr);

myVar = "newValue"; //Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
console.log(myVar);
```

You can also see on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/am2cbb00/1/

Comment: So... what would something like this do, at the top of a function? `const obj = new myObject(this, data);` I'm not sure if it's like a static in PHP or more like a ..ehm.. singleton pattern perhaps, but with.. erhm... "resuable" constructor? Or perhaps just a programmer showing off his shiny new keyword for no reason....

Comment: @ChristofferBubach it's a constructor in javascript. "new" keyword is used to create an instance of an object. Basically, it creates a new object and assigns a const variable to it. So, that const variable cannot be bind with an another object. Only the content of object can be changed and updated. Please also check here for "new" keyword usage in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: I know what I constructor is - my question is rather: what happens the second time the function is called?  Is the object re-initialized with the new data-variable, or is it more like a static between calls? I find it unclear why one would use it inside a function like this.

Comment: @ChristofferBubach when the function is called second time, it initialises completely a new instance of "myObject" but it's not possible to assign that new instance to the same "obj" variable because it's defined constant variable. In your example, constructor owner also passes current object scope with "this". It might be possible that developer wants to reach some variable from that scope in the constructor.

Comment: So question is, would it be appropriate (best practise wise) to use an object if you are going to change/reassign its properties or not?

Answer (score 10):

let and const are meant for type safety. There is no situation where you **must** use them, but they can be handy and reduce hard to spot bugs.

One example of a situation where const would be useful for an object that you don't want to turn into another type.

```
const x = {"hello":"world"};

// This is OK
x.hello = "stackoverflow";

// This is not OK
x = JSON.stringify(x);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you work with an object and want to make sure that identity of the object is never changed say:

```
const a = {};

a.b = 1;

// ... somewhere in the other part of the code or from an async call
// suddenly

someAjaxCall().then(() => { a = null; }) // for preventing this
```

Also using `const` is a good hint for javascript compiler to make optimisations about your code, thus making execution much faster then with `let` or `var` because the identity never changes,

**BUT**

beware of using const/let in loops for performance reasons, because it might  slowdown the performance due to creation of a variable per loop, but in most cases the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

`const` actually creates immutable binding instead of making the variables immutable.

Since primitive data-types (`Boolean`, `null`, `undefined`, `String`, and `Number`) are passed by value, they themselves become immutable and hence can't be re-assigned to some other value.

In the case of complex data-types (`Array`, `Function`, and `Object`), they are passed by reference. When we change or modify their properties/elements, we not changing their binding, hence `const` doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

`const` makes the `name` AND content immutable UNLESS the content is an object, then only the content can be changed.

```js
const n = 1; 
n = 2; // Uncaught type error
let n = 2 // Already assigned
```