# What is the preferred declaration convention for objects or arrays: const or let?

Tags: javascript, standards, tslint

I'm not asking what's technically possible; I know you can do

```
const a = [];
const b = {};
a.push['sup'];
b.test = 'earth';
```

What I'm wondering is whether there's any convention for preferring `let` over `const` when it comes to arrays and objects that will have their internals modified. If you see an object declared with `const`, do you assume the intention was for the object to be immutable, and would you have preferred to see `let` instead, or, since some linters (like tslint) have a problem with that, is it better just to declare it with `const` and trust that anyone else reading the code knows that that doesn't mean it's immutable?

Comment: I prefer `const` for this purpose, because the variable will always refer to the same object. But if it's your code, use whatever you prefer. If you work in a team and are worried they might get confused then write a coding standards document for the team: problem solved.

Comment: Always use `const` if possible. If you really need to freeze the object, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze.

Comment: You forgot `var`, still the preferred way to declare a variable that doesn't need special scoping rules or immutable behaviour

Comment: @adeneo I disagree. I never use `var` anymore. There's really no reason to. As for which to use, `let` or `const`, that's all up to opinion. If I intend for something to not be touched, I use `const`. If it *really* shouldn't be touched, and it's some kind of object, I use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Comment: IMO, there’s no reason not to declare arrays and objects with `const`, since you’re most likely not going to redefine `a` and `b`. _I personally_ know that it doesn’t mean that they are immutable; for immutability I would use e.g. `Object.freeze`, but someone else might misinterpret that…

Comment: As the comments already show, there is no best-practice convention on this. It is a matter of preference. As such, I'm voting to close this question as it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @MikeC - I use `var` all the time, and only use the other two when they make things easier. If you never find a reason to use variables that aren't block scoped, that's up to you, I do.

Comment: @adeneo `var` just uses function scoping rather than block scoping. If I intend to use a variable through a function then I declare it at the function scope with `let` or `const`. Declaring variables in child blocks which are then used in parent or siblings blocks is confusing and uncomfortable in my opinion.

Comment: Come up with your own convention (and write it down) and stick to it. Consistency is the most important here.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604212/when-to-use-const-with-objects-in-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843572/how-to-create-javascript-constants-as-properties-of-objects-using-const-keyword

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `const` keyword in front of an object implies that there is an object, and you're working with ***references*** to alter it. It also (correctly) implies that you should not attempt to reassign references to this object.

```
const obj = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'};

const obj2 = {z: 'baz'};

obj = obj2; // const will prevent this operation.
```

**`const` does not imply that the object properties should not be altered. It does imply that you should not try to change the reference.**

If you plan to reassign references to the object, then you use `let`.

Source: [AirBnB Javascript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#references)

Comment: Thanks. I'd say if it's good enough for Airbnb, it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 18):

> I favor `const` over `let` in ES6. In JavaScript, `const` means that
>   the identifier can’t be reassigned. (Not to be confused with immutable
>   values. Unlike true immutable datatypes such as those produced by
>   Immutable.js and Mori, a `const` object can have properties mutated.)
>
> If I don’t need to reassign, `const` is my default choice over `let`
>   because I want the usage to be as clear as possible in the code.
>
> I use `let` when I need to reassign a variable. Because I use one
>   variable to represent one thing, the use case for `let` tends to be
>   for loops or mathematical algorithms.

Reference: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75#.9s2e58ihw

Example from MDN: 
The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.

```
const name1 = value1 [, name2 = value2 [, ... [, nameN = valueN]]];
```

> nameN
>       The constant's name, which can be any legal identifier. valueN
>       The constant's value; this can be any legal expression.

The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

```
let var1 [= value1] [, var2 [= value2]] [, ..., varN [= valueN]];
```

> var1, var2, …, varN
>       Variable name. It can be any legal identifier. value1, value2, …, valueN
>       Initial value of the variable. It can be any legal expression.

From my opinion, it fairly depends on what you want to do with them. I found the statements above convincing enough to share with you.

Answer (score 10):

There is no preferred one, its based on your choice of usage for that array or object. You have to understand mutation and reassigning clearly.

> **Mutation - updates the values present in the memory**
>
> **Reassign - variable points to new memory locations where new values are stored**

**Let - offers both mutation and reassiging**

**Const - offers mutation but not reassiging**

**Both - doesnot offers redeclaring**

If your usecase only needs mutation, you can  go for const.. if you need reassigning then go for let.

```js
// LET

let condiments = ['Ketchup', 'Soy Sauce', 'Sriracha'];

// Mutation possible
condiments[0] = 'Mayo';
console.log(condiments);//=> [ 'Mayo', 'Soy Sauce', 'Sriracha' ]

// Re-assigning possible
condiments = ['Mayo'];
console.log(condiments); //=> [ 'Mayo' ]

// Re-declaring not possible
//let condiments = [] //=> SyntaxError: Identifier 'condiments' has already been declared


// CONST

const utensils = ['Fork', 'Chopsticks', 'Spork'];

// Mutation Possible
utensils[2] = 'Spoon'
console.log(utensils); //=> [ 'Fork', 'Chopsticks', 'Spoon' ]
utensils.length = 0
console.log(utensils); //=> [ ]

// Re-assigning not possible
//utensils = ['Spoon']; //=> TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

// Re-declaring not possible
//const utensils = {} //=> SyntaxError: Identifier 'condiments' has already been declared
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a question you wont be able to get a final answer for, as it is very opinion-based.

A little bit of historical background can help to understand how the confusing `const` came to be in the first place:

[Allan Wirfs-Brock, the former editor of the EcmaScript spec, himself said:](https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/699281411291766784)

> In a slightly different (and perhaps better) universe, ECMAScript `const` declaration would be named `let` and introduce a SSA binding.

And asked, why this was not the case, [he responded](https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/699285374737121281):

> let/const was a carry over from ES4 proposals and Moz JS1.7
>
> TC39 never seriously explored naming alternatives

So you could say `const` is a bit of a misnomer, since it doesn't do what people who aren't familiar with it might expect it to do.

Since `const` works the way it does though and is almost certainly not going to change, **I would still define your objects with `const`**.

This might help people who are unfamiliar with the way `const` works to get a better understanding.

Maybe it could help to add a comment at the first occurrence of `const` with an object, along the lines of:

```
// Important: 'const' only ensures that 'styles' always references the same object,
// it does not render it immutable
const styles = {};
```

Opinions may vary though.