# Passing an array from php to js

Tags: javascript, php, json, file

I've file with extension php. In here I've read information from Database. And I need to pass this data(associate array) to js, which also include in this php file.

```
<?php
    require('../db.php');

    function var_dump1($arr) {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($arr);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    // load data from Database
    $query = R::getAll("SELECT * from questions");
    var_dump1($query);

?>

<script>
const arr = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($query); ?>' );
console.log(arr);

</script>
```

Outputs:

> var_dump1($query);

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["question"]=>
    string(143) "The ______________ of a table is used to modify the design of a table, like modifying the name of a field or changing the data type of a field."
    ["answer1"]=>
    string(14) "Datasheet View"
    ["answer2"]=>
    string(11) "Desisn View"
    ["answer3"]=>
    string(10) "Table View"
    ["answer4"]=>
    string(11) "Wizard View"
    ["true_answer"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["question"]=>
    string(83) "You can select multiple fields of a table in design view by using the ________ key."
    ["answer1"]=>
    string(3) "Alt"
    ["answer2"]=>
    string(8) "Spacebar"
    ["answer3"]=>
    string(5) "Shift"
    ["answer4"]=>
    string(4) "Ctrl"
    ["true_answer"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
...
```

> console.log(arr);

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Conclusion:
On the part of php all good. But when we try to parse this array in js object in js part - We see strange Error.

Questions:

1. How to load data(For example, associate array, in my case) from php to js. When php and js are in the same extension file(php).
2. 1. How to load data(For example, associate array, in my case) from php to js. When php and js are in different files. For example We've 1 extension file php, where we've implement logic(With DB, in my case). And we need to import this data to extension file js.

Comment: Why are you using `var_dump` instead of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Comment: Post the source code of your rendered page (JS part only)

Comment: You need to `json_encode` before you `json.parse`

Comment: @Richard he is already encoding it.

Comment: @MehdiBounya var dump is not encoding it and doesn't meet json parse requirements

Comment: @Richard Yes, but `json_encode` is... read the code again

Comment: In fact, just do this only: `const arr = <?php echo json_encode($query); ?>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) All you need to do is this:

```
<script>
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($query);?>; // <-- no quotes, no parsify
console.log(arr);
</script>
```

JSON = JavaScript Object Notation... its already in the format to assign to a variable to use in javascript.

Although assigning it to a 'const' is ... probably not a good idea since its an object, but its just how I read them, and still perfectly ok: [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604534/2960971).

2) If you are calling a php file from js (ala ajax), then you can return raw JSON from the php return, and depending on HOW you made your ajax call (and with what library, like possibly jquery)... you may or may not need to do `JSON.parse(returnData)`. Not enough information provided how you want to do that, to give a solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about [JSON](https://www.json.org/).
It's a syntax that can be parsed with any language incliding JS.

just echo your array with PHP to your JacaScript code like this :

```
<script>
var myData = <?php echo json_encode($array);?>;
console.log(myData);
</script>
```

Comment: =D ... sometimes SO lags

Comment: Yes ia agree :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally your php - code will render to an html - page. In this page, you can structure data, depending on your needs. Examples (in your php - code):

```
// as a js - variable: 
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
var questions = <?php echo json_encode($query);
?>
alert(questions); // Output whatever is in the questions-variable
</script>
```

questions will be a global js-variable you can reach 
from another js.file, or from js embedded in a html-file.

```
// As data in your html: 
<input type="hidden" id="id_questions" name="questions" 
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($query)); ?>"
/>
// Then fetch this data using js-code, eg in a different js-file: 
alert(document.getElementById('id_questions').value());
```

This can also be reached either from an external js file, or from js embedded in the html-output form your php-code.