# Modifying an array element using filter method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pusher

I'm trying to modify an element in a list in Vue.js using `.filter()` method. The new element comes from Pusher. I'm listening for the event and trying to update the element like this:

```js
users.filter((obj) => {
    Echo.private(`user.${obj.id}`).listen('.userupdated', (e) => {
        return obj = e.user; // or return e.user; also doesn't work
    });
});
```

This doesn't work. Both objects are identical in terms of their structure, but the new object coming through Pusher contains the updated information.

On the other hand, when I try to modify a property, it works:

```js
users.filter((obj) => {
    Echo.private(`user.${obj.id}`).listen('.userupdated', (e) => {
        return obj.name = e.user.name;
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is replacing an entire element like this isn't allowed?

Comment: *I'm trying to modify an element in a list in Vue.js using `.filter()` method.* It doesn't sound a good use case for `filter`.

Comment: @Psidom thanks for your comment. Can you please suggest a better way to subscribe to multiple Pusher channels?

Comment: A return to a callback doesn't return to the outer function. On top of that filter() is synchronous. All you are doing with the filter is using it as a loop and that is not it's purpose

Comment: A simple for loop should do it? Use the index to modify the original array?

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for your comment, but why `return obj.name = e.user.name;` is working?

Comment: @Rehmat working how? Not in the filter since you aren't doing anything with the array returned by filter

Comment: @Psidom Thank you! I tried to avoid that as I was surprised to see that `return obj.name = e.user.name;` worked but `return obj = e.user;` did not.

Comment: @Rehmat it is working as it's kind of a hack you are using to modify your object's properties on a go, which shouldn't be that way.

Comment: @charlietfl when I try to update the properties, it works; i.e. `return obj.name = e.user.name;` updates the `name` property but `return obj = e.user;` didn't update the object.

Comment: `obj.name` works because `obj` by itself is a reference that points to an object, so you are modifying the underlying object by doing `obj.name = e.user.name`. While with `obj = e.user`, you are overwriting the `obj` variable which doesn't affect what references are stored in the original array.

Comment: @Rehmat modifying the property would work the same without the `return`. You are not returning to the outer function from that callback because returns don't work that way

Comment: Thank for all your help. I'll use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) what filter does is this:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

So what you are doing is basically using Filter in the wrong way. 
What you should do is on an event fires iterate over the old array and update it as it goes.

My suggestion: On an event fire call a function that serves just that purpose with newer value and place to replace it on and then programmatically deal with it!

Comment: My concern is, if it is the wrong way to achieve the results, then why `return obj.name = e.user.name;` is working?

Comment: @Rehmat It is a kind of hack you are using there which is letting you modify the object's properties on the go but that shouldn't be that way and you are right, it is working but it is clearly not the appropriate behaviour. Object properties can be modified but it's variable reference can't much like object with const keywords, you can change it's properties but can't assign a new object

Comment: I'm upvoting the answer. Thank you! p.s. Will wait for a better answer and if I don't get a better answer, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: @Rehmat That's great, thanks, again, to make your code modular make a function specifically to deal with array on events. And if you are looking for better explanation of how object's properties assignment work but not the whole object's reassignment doesn't work, I think you should look up objects initialization, how it's stores and behaves, maybe see how object works after creating it with const keyword, it's the same behaviour

Comment: @Rehmat Check this out to know more about Obj behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604212/when-to-use-const-with-objects-in-javascript